# How to parse a big .xlsx file with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, parsing

I tried to parse my file with >38k rows using read-excel-file, but it doesn't support so big files (that has written the developer of lib in issues). People write, that xlsx-stream-reader  also can not handle big files.

It'd be very cool, if you know any lib, that can handle it.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx seems promising. Haven't tested it myself, but [one of their closed issues](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx/issues/130) mentions something about handling large file (> 80MB)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs